# How to click on the below image using python? with SRC / ALT

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

```
<img src="https://secure.ce-tescoassets.com/UIAssets/CZ/grocery/default/en-GB/i231/btn-switch-clickCollect.png" alt="Select Click and Collect" id="yui_3_14_1_1_1414068339185_100">
```

Tried using java however that doesn't to work with Python Ride 2.7.2

```
selenium.click("//img[contains(@alt,'Select') and contains(@alt,'Click and Collect')]");

selenium.click("css=img[alt*='Select'][alt*='Click and Collect']");
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please explain how exactly that "doesn't work". In my tests, your XPATH expression should match just fine, and selenium should click that item just fine. Also, you have this tagged as `Python`, but don't show any python code. You also mention `Java` in your question, so is this Python or Java?

Comment: Yo can't click it through python, you need some front-end interface to cake it click. If you want to track the click means you can send some request when clicks. Though it works better if you use jQuery. BTW welcome to stackoverflow.